# Parameterzing the zip file input

Tags: java

I have written the code below to unzip files in eclipse as a part of my application. I don't want user to go inside the code and input the file name  each time (`String str="C:/user/module/file.zip"`) they want to unzip any file. I want to parameterize the input zip file name.
kindly help me to solve this issue.

```
class demo{
public static void main(String[] args[]) {
        demo bn=new demo();
        String str="C:/user/module/file.zip";
        bn.unzip_file(str);
    }
```

Comment: For this you can use `args`

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself - the java naming convention is UpperCamelCase for classes, and lowerCamelCase for methods and variables.  So your class should be `Demo`, and its method called `unzipFile()`.  This might seem like a small thing but it makes your code surprisingly harder to read for others.

Answer (score 1):

The `args` variable contains the command line parameters, with `args[0]` containing the path of the executable. Instead of hard coding the string, use this parameter.

Comment: thanks Femaref,Andrzej and CAMOBAP :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class demo{
public static void main(String[] args[]) {
        demo bn=new demo();
        String str= args[0]; // provided zip file path from command line.
        bn.unzip_file(str);
    }
```